# Question on Oracle rowid column in every table

Tags: oracle

I want to know how to use the ***object number*** that extract from rowid column? It's seems that this ***oracle number*** is not the same as **object_id** in **dba_objects** view. Anyone can help me with it please? Thanks.

```
sys@ORCL>l
  1  SELECT rowid, DBMS_ROWID.Rowid_object(ROWID)   "OBJECT",
  2     DBMS_ROWID.Rowid_relative_fno(ROWID) "FILE",
  3     DBMS_ROWID.Rowid_block_number(ROWID) "BLOCK",
  4     DBMS_ROWID.Rowid_row_number(ROWID)   "ROW",
  5     employee_id, first_name
  6  FROM   hr.employees
  7* WHERE  department_id = 30
sys@ORCL>/

ROWID              OBJECT       FILE      BLOCK    ROW EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME
------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- --------------------
AAAR5pAAFAAAADPAAO  73321          5    207     14         114 first_name
AAAR5pAAFAAAADPAAP  73321          5    207     15         115 first_name
AAAR5pAAFAAAADPAAQ  73321          5    207     16         116 first_name
AAAR5pAAFAAAADPAAR  73321          5    207     17         117 first_name
AAAR5pAAFAAAADPAAS  73321          5    207     18         118 first_name
AAAR5pAAFAAAADPAAT  73321          5    207     19         119 first_name

6 rows selected.

sys@ORCL>select * from dba_objects where object_id = 73321;

no rows selected

sys@ORCL>
```

Comment: Have you read [this](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2008/10/21/transportable-tablespaces-and-rowid-uniqueness/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer of my own question. The so called **object number** from `DBMS_ROWID.Rowid_object` corresponds to **dba_objects.data_object_id**, not **object_id**.

```
sys@ORCL>select owner, object_name, object_id, data_object_id from dba_objects where data_object_id = 73321;

OWNER    OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_ID  DATA_OBJECT_ID
-------- ----------- ---------- --------------
HR       EMPLOYEES   73953      73321

sys@ORCL>
```

Answer (score 2):

An *object_id* identifies an object (such as a table, or an index) within Oracle.

The *rowid* can only be used for tables, or more specifically: the records within tables. It uniquely identifes such a record, that is, where the record can be found on the harddisk.

Therefore, the function *DBMS_ROWID.Rowid_relative_fno* gives you an id that identifies the file, *DBMS_ROWID.Rowid_block_number* gives you the block within that file and *DBMS_ROWID.Rowid_row_number* gives you the "row offset" within that block of the actual record.

In your case, you can query *v$datafile* with the file_id of 5 to find out which file "holds" the record. `select name from v$datafile where file# = 5`.

Comment: What does the ***DBMS_ROWID.Rowid_object*** mean?